# unable to redirect to a custom action in devise registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Excuse me for the noob question.

I have a devise users model and i want to save additional data to the users model after a user signs_in/signs_up.

routes.rb

```
     devise_for :users,
        path: '',
        path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout',sign_up: 'signup'},
        controllers: { registrations: 'registrations

        devise_scope :user do 
             match 'users/customer' => 'registrations#customer', :via => [:get], :as => 'customer'
             match 'users/theme-selector' => 'registrations#theme_selector', :via => [:get], :as => 'theme-selector'
        end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    protect_from_forgery :except => :create

      def customer
      @user = current_user

    if @user
       render :customer
     # render :customer
     # redirect_to controller: 'registations', action: 'theme_selector'


        else
            render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
         end   


  end



    def theme_selector
         @user = current_user
            if @user
                render :theme_selector
            else
                render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
             end 


       end 

       end
      end
```

customer.html.erb

```
 <div class="container huge-top small-bottom"">
  <div class="row large-top">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|  %>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Contact Person" %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Business Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class:"form-control", required: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Mailing Address" %>
    <%= f.text_field :address, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :"Do you currently have a domain?" %>
    <%= f.text_area :domain, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-5">
   <!--%= f.submit '+', :name => "add_additional_fields" %-->
    <span><%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-success" %></span>
<span><!--%= link_to 'Back', customers_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %--></span>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

The steps are:

1.A user signs_up or sign_in.

2.The user then selects customer button which renders customer.html.erb

3.After submitting the customer form ,then it has to redirect to theme_selector page to select a certain theme.

I could update the users model by submitting the data inside the **customer.html.erb** form .now I want to redirect to the theme_selector page and then pass in the theme_id to the users model.If i use **redirect_to controller: 'registations', action: 'theme_selector'** in the customer action , it is skipping customer form and rendering theme_selector page.How can I make it to redirect to theme_selector after the customer form.

theme_selector.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|  %>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top-space">
      <!-- thumbnail-->
      <div class="thumbnail image-height">
        <a href="http://theme1./" target="_blank">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="/assets/1.jpg" class="img-responsive theme" alt="">

              <div class="price-sale"><img src="/assets/new.png"></div>

          </div>  
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Click Here</h4>
            <!--p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p-->
            <p><button class="btn-update" role="button">View</button></p>
          </div>
        </a>  
      </div>
      <div><%= f.radio_button :theme_id, 'theme-1' %> </div>
    <!-- thumbnail end -->
    </div>   
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 top-space">
      <!-- thumbnail-->
      <div class="thumbnail image-height">
        <a href="http://theme2/" target="_blank">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="/assets/2.jpg" class="img-responsive theme" alt="">

              <div class="price-sale"><img src="/assets/new.png"></div>

          </div>  
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>Click Here</h4>
            <!--p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, soluta, eligendi doloribus sunt minus amet sit debitis repellat. Consectetur, culpa itaque odio similique suscipit</p-->
            <p><button class="btn-update" role="button">View</button></p>
          </div>
        </a>  
      </div>
      <div><%= f.radio_button :theme_id, 'theme-1' %> </div>
    <!-- thumbnail end -->
    </div>
     <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 top-space"><%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "btn-addmore" %></div>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

Any Help or suggestion is highly Appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: does https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L112 work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

[Easy solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) will be:

In your `config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users,
    path: '',
    path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout',sign_up: 'signup'},
    controllers: { registrations: 'registrations}

    devise_scope :user do 
        get 'users/theme-selector' => 'registrations#theme_selector', :as => 'theme-selector'
```

In your `registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'users/theme-selector'
  end
end
```

Comment: Michael ,Thanks for the quick response.I apologize for not making my question clear.
Actually the steps are:
1.A user signs_up or signs_in.
2.The user selects customer button which renders customer.html.erb
3.After submitting the customer form ,then it has to redirect to theme_selector page.

Comment: @suresh This form is not sign_up/sign_in form?